# How to remove the blue color in selected tab pane

Tags: css, javafx-8

I'm working on javafx project, I have a FXML interface where I put a tab pane, when I select a tab , the border of the selected button is colored in blue, but the style I want is to let the white color will add no border.

My image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwedh.png) has a blue outline.
[image: tab with blue border]

to get this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiBIW.png)

[image: tab without blue border]

my Css code for styling Tab pane:

```css
.tab
{
    -fx-background-color: #fbfbfb;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2
}
.tab:selected 
{
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color: #fbfbfb;
    -fx-border-width: 0 0 3 0;
    -fx-border-color: #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2 #ff9500 #c2c2c2
}
.tab-pane *.tab-header-background 
{
    -fx-background-color: #fbfbfb, #fbfbfb, #fbfbfb;
    -fx-border-width: 1 0 1 0;
    -fx-border-color: #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2 #c2c2c2
}
```

Comment: perhaps clarify exactly what you are asking?

Comment: wow, what is this '-fx-'? Seen it 1st time in css

Comment: when I select a tab , the border of the selected button is colored in blue,  but the style I want is to let the white color will add no border , I put two photos above .

Comment: @Oussama i don't know about '-fx-' friend can you please tell me what is it used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

> To find the default ‪stylesheet of tabPane‬, I looked for the file
>   ‎jfxrt‬.jar in my computer, and I open it in an archiver like WinRAR to
>   get ‪‎caspian‬.css at com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/caspian.css.
>   With this knowledge, I can easily see what could be there that
>   causes the issue. caspian.css is also available online, here is the a
>   link to the JavaFX 2.2 version.

---

my need is the code below :

```html
.tab-pane:focused > .tab-header-area > .headers-region > .tab:selected .focus-indicator {
     -fx-border-style: segments(0.166667em, 0.166667em);
     -fx-border-width: 1;
     -fx-border-color: -fx-focus-color;
}
```

I changed the color **-fx-focus-color: #0093ff;** (blue color in selected tab)

Answer (score -1):

Set the outline property to 0

```
.tab
{
   outline :0;
}
```